# Get Tag property from ToolStripMenuItem and Button in click event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a method set to the click event handler in several Buttons and ToolStripMenuItems.

I want to get the Tag property of the sender to see which was clicked, but seems like  ToolStripMenuItems can't be casted to Control.

How can I get the Tag property of both Buttons and ToolStripMenuItems?

Here's a simplified version of my method.

```
private void menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((Control)sender).Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "X":
                // do something
                break;
            case "Y":
                //do something else
                break;
            default:
                //something else
                break;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's no common base class or interface of Button and ToolStripMenuItem that defines Tag, you will need to do a cast:

```
internal static object GetTag(object sender)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;
  ToolStripItem tsi = sender as ToolStripItem;

  if (button != null)
    return button.Tag;
  if (tsi != null)
    return tsi.Tag;

  throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected sender");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I though the `as` operator was just another way to say `(type)object`